# Capybara: How to find a text in <td> using the label included in the cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, label, capybara

I have a table with cells like that:

```
<td colspan="2">
  <label for="stammdaten_bundesland_id">Bundesland</label>
  Nordrhein-Westfalen
</td>
```

How could I access that text in td using label?

I would like to have a step:

```
I should see "Nordrhein-Westfalen" within cell with label for "stammdaten_bundesland_id"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" within the cell with label for "([^"]*)"$/ do |text, label|
  page.should have_xpath("//td[./label[@for=\"#{label}\"]]", :text => text)
end
```